# Need to freeze EXTJS grid

Tags: extjs

EXTJS Grid consists of Rows and columns.
Need to freeze the first column in the Grid.
 If we use enabling locking true then data in the rows is getting blank. please refer image. All the cells in the rows are getting blank after enabling locking true

Can any one suggest what can be the best solution to freeze the column without impacting the data in Grid.[Highlighted part should be freezed and user can add any number of rows if he wants, we need to freeze only first column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnzo2.png)

Comment: Please give an example of the code. There is no other good way to do it, locking feature is the way to go. Probably, you are doing sth wrong.

Comment: Please refer https://paste.ee/p/BduvS       for code

Comment: We need the same as below eg http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/grid/locking-grp-summary-grp-hdrs-grid.html

Comment: Html code doesnt mean anything. I need js code to inspect. If you implement the same code as in the example, there must be sth you are missing.

Comment: Please make a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) with a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your problem.